# How to a find div inside multiple div values, in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have data like this

```
      <div class="small-box bg-aqua">
          <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit white"></i></button>
          </div>
        <div class="inner">
          <h4 class="show"><?=$row->name?></h4>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control hide" value="<?=$row->name?>" />
          <p>Customer</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And I have a jQuery like this

```
$('.glyphicon-edit').click(function() {
    var x = $( this ).find('.inner').find('.hide').val();
    alert(x);
});
```

How can I get the hide class value, in jQuery?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0LgL7f9y/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.glyphicon-edit').click(function() {
    var x = $(this).closest('.small-box').find('input[type="text"]').val();
    alert(x);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
$('.glyphicon-edit').click(function() {
    var x = $( this ).parents('.small-box').find('.hide').val();
    alert(x);
});
```

Comment: @PraveenSrinivasan If you find it is working, Do approve the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
$('.glyphicon-edit').click(function () {
    alert($(".hide").val()); 
});
```

[JSFiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/p1bpw2ku/)

Comment: Please note that the event was attached to the icon and not the surrounding area. Therefore you need to click on the icon itself and not on the surrounding area :)

Answer (score 0):

Use 'btn-box-tool' class instead of 'glyphicon-edit'

```
$('.btn-box-tool').click(function () {
    var x = $(this).closest('.small-box').find('.inner .hide').val();
    alert(x);
});
```